# How to iterate over every n-th line from a file?

Tags: python, file

First, I am new to Python and did search for answers, but no luck. So far what I found only returns a one line like my code below. I tried other solutions like `itertools.islice` but always only get a one line back.

I have a file called `data.txt` containing lines of data:

```
This is line one
This is line two 
This is line three 
This is line four 
This is line five 
This is line six 
This is line seven 
...
```

I have the following code:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for x, line in enumerate(f):
        if x == 3:
            print(line)
```

In this case it only prints

> "This is line four".

I do understand why but how do I take it from here and have it print the lines 4, 7, 10, 13, ...?

Comment: True. I will need to start at line 1. Based on the solution provided below I can do "for line in islice(f, 0, None, 3):" The next step is to figure out how to deal with empty rows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The return value of [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) is an iterator (and thus, iterable), so you can pass it to [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

> islice(iterable, start, stop[, step]) --> islice object
> Return an iterator whose next() method returns selected values from an
> iterable. [...]

Demo:

`data.txt`:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
line9
line10
line11
line12
line13
```

Code:

```
from itertools import islice

with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in islice(f, 3, None, 3):
        print line,  # Python3: print(line, end='')
```

Produces:

```
line4
line7
line10
line13
```

Comment: Thank you for the demo. That worked like a charm. It made me realize that my problem is with my source file. For this post I used a simple data file to explain what I am trying to achieve. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for x, line in enumerate(f):
        if x and x % 3 == 0:
            print(line)
```