# Cycle for to add to dictionary from file in a comprehension view

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have a file contains this (actually it has much more lines it is only a part):

```
@SRR12345678.1
GAGCCATATGACCACGCCGGAGAATCTCGCCAAGCAGGCAAAGCTGATGGAAGGCTACGGTGCGCCCTGTTTTTAT
+SRR12345678.1
-@CCCGGGGFFGGCFGGGEEDFDFFGDFCEE,:@FDC8FE8,@FC8FFC,EFDFGE@FA,C9CE99F@7B7+CCE,CF,,6C,,C,+8++8++
@SRR12345678.5
CTTTATGCCCCCACAGTGCGATCAGGAAGTACATCGGCACCAGCATCATTTCCCAGAAGAAGAAGAACATGAACAT
+SRR12345678.5
CCCCCGFGGGGGDGDCFCFEDFEEDC?CDE9FAFGECF>FF8,C,FE8CEEFFF,,,,,,,,,,,,,C,,,,,:,:
@SRR12345678.6
GTCGATGGCCTGAACTACTCACGCTTCGAGAAGCAGATGCCTGCGCTGGCAGGTTTTGCTGAGCAAAATATTTCGT
+SRR12345678.6
-ACCCGFFGGGFCFGGGGGGGGCFGEGD8C878FAFGGCEFFEF7CFC7@,A+CEFD,CF,,,:,,,,:,
```

And I have a code to add this to dictionary:

```
file = open("test.fastq")

d={}
for i in file:
    d_key, *d_value = i.split()
    d[d_key] = d_value
```

Can I somehow write the cycle in one line in a comprehension view (to have one-line code)? I need to use dictionary only because the file is really big.

Comment: What is the expected output? (Here you will just create a dictionary with the full strings as keys and empty lists as value). Are you aware that there are specialized tools to handle fastq files?

Comment: Don't strive for one-line code just "because of it". A future you (or a colleague) will be quite annoyed trying to decipher it.

Comment: @mozway, sure. This is a learning ex. I`m trying to handle out a big file with python. The output - is a dictionary.

Comment: @AKX, it was just a question. Yes or now.

Comment: Yes you can, but I believe the output is a bit weird. Do you really expect something like`{'@SRR12345678.1': [], 'GAGCCATATGACCACGCCGGAGAATCTCGCCAAGCAGGCAAAGCTGATGGAAGGCTACGGTGCGCCCTGTTTTTAT': [],  '+SRR12345678.1': [], ...}` as output? Doesn't really make much sense…

Comment: @vaizki, there is a syntax error somewhere...

Comment: @vaizki this is not valid code, you can't assign in a comprehension like you did

Comment: @mozway, I need to have in dictionary every 2-nd line

Comment: @Breatheoffate your current code doesn't do any "every second line" stuff either.

Comment: @AKX, I know this. This code just add every line to the dic with [""] values. It was just a try to add smth in a dict if the file is really big.

Comment: @Breatheoffate So you say "you have this code to add this to a dictionary", but it _doesn't even do what you want it to do_?

Answer (score 1):

If you want every second line as key/data, one way could be to take advantage of the file iterator:

```
with open("test.fastq") as f:
    d = {i.strip(): next(f).strip() for i in f}
```

*NB. this requires an even number of lines!*

To handle odd numbers of lines.

- Setting up a default value:

```
with open("/tmp/test.fastq") as f:
    d = {i.strip(): next(f, '').strip() for i in f}
```

- dropping the lone key:

```
with open("/tmp/test.fastq") as f:
    d = {i.strip(): s.strip() for i in f if (s:=next(f, None))}
```

output:

```
{'@SRR12345678.1': 'GAGCCATATGACCACGCCGGAGAATCTCGCCAAGCAGGCAAAGCTGATGGAAGGCTACGGTGCGCCCTGTTTTTAT',
 '+SRR12345678.1': '-@CCCGGGGFFGGCFGGGEEDFDFFGDFCEE,:@FDC8FE8,@FC8FFC,EFDFGE@FA,C9CE99F@7B7+CCE,CF,,6C,,C,+8++8++',
 '@SRR12345678.5': 'CTTTATGCCCCCACAGTGCGATCAGGAAGTACATCGGCACCAGCATCATTTCCCAGAAGAAGAAGAACATGAACAT',
 '+SRR12345678.5': 'CCCCCGFGGGGGDGDCFCFEDFEEDC?CDE9FAFGECF>FF8,C,FE8CEEFFF,,,,,,,,,,,,,C,,,,,:,:',
 '@SRR12345678.6': 'GTCGATGGCCTGAACTACTCACGCTTCGAGAAGCAGATGCCTGCGCTGGCAGGTTTTGCTGAGCAAAATATTTCGT',
 '+SRR12345678.6': '-ACCCGFFGGGFCFGGGGGGGGCFGEGD8C878FAFGGCEFFEF7CFC7@,A+CEFD,CF,,,:,,,,:,'}
```

Comment: Yigh, using `next()` on the same iterable that's being iterated over by a dictcomp sounds like it will break sooner or later.

Comment: @AKX it will only break if the number of lines is odd. But sure, I would rather write a clean parser for real work (not what is being asked here though).

Comment: I added example of how to handle odd number of lines

Comment: @mozway, is it possible to have like this:
1:next(f)? (number of entry:a line)

Comment: Not sure what this means

Comment: @mozway

`{1: GAGCCATATGACCACGCCGGAGAATCTCGCCAAGCAGGCAAAGCTGATGGAAGGCTACGGTGCGCCCTGTTTTTAT,
2: CTTTATGCCCCCACAGTGCGATCAGGAAGTACATCGGCACCAGCATCATTTCCCAGAAGAAGAAGAACATGAACAT,
3: GTCGATGGCCTGAACTACTCACGCTTCGAGAAGCAGATGCCTGCGCTGGCAGGTTTTGCTGAGCAAAATATTTCGT}` etc...

Comment: Yes, just read every 4th line. Using a dictionary with a range as key is however useless a simple list would be better.

Comment: @mozway, sure. I made a solution with list but is took really a long time if the file is really big (several thousands entries). How can I read every 4th line?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36487709/how-to-iterate-over-every-n-th-line-from-a-file