# when reading from a file, why is my output not as expected?

Tags: python, split, readfile

I am reading in a file that contains several lines that are of the format 'Grid-ref=   x, y' where x and y is meant to be split and asigned to 2 variables xref and yref. I use the following code to do this

```
l = 5
x = 1
for line in lines[5:]:
   if l == ((11*x) - 6):
      xref, yref = line[11*x - 6:].replace("Grid-", "").replace("ref=", "").replace(" ", "").strip().split(',')
      x = x + 1
      l = l + 1
      continue
```

x starts from 1 and increments every time this line is run. the reason it is 11x - 6 is because the gridref line comes every 11 lines in the file, so it is always at line 11x - 6 where x is an integer, the rest of the lines are data. here is the first 30 lines of the file just to give more context

```
Tyndall Centre grim file created on 22.01.2004 at 17:57 by Dr. Tim Mitchell
.pre = precipitation (mm)
CRU TS 2.1
[Long=-180.00, 180.00] [Lati= -90.00,  90.00] [Grid X,Y= 720, 360]
[Boxes=   67420] [Years=1991-2000] [Multi=    0.1000] [Missing=-999]
Grid-ref=   1, 148
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
Grid-ref=   1, 311
  490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460  420  530  450
  490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460  420  530  450
  490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460  420  530  450
  490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460  420  530  450
  490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460  420  530  450
  490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460  420  530  450
  490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460  420  530  450
  490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460  420  530  450
  490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460  420  530  450
  490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460  420  530  450
Grid-ref=   1, 312
  460  280  260  220  190  240  430  520  450  400  520  410
  460  280  260  220  190  240  430  520  450  400  520  410
```

so for example, 'Grid-ref=   1, 311' should assign 1 and 311 to xref and yref respectively. This seems to work for the first instance of 'Grid-ref', but then the second time this occurs, this line of code seems to result in only the last 2 digits being stored. so for 'Grid-ref=   1, 311' it returns a single value '11' rather than 1 and 311. can anyone see why that is? This line of code obviously works as it works for the first value, and i can't see why it is giving a wrong result. any help would be much appreciated

I have put print statements to ensure that it is indeed on the correct line and this is the case

Comment: What is `x` and what should the whole `11*x - 6` expression cut from the line?

Comment: Can you give a little bit more context, for example by showing an example where it works as expected and show where `x` and `line` come from? Is `line` the full content of the file or is it part of a loop, like `for line in lines:`?

Comment: @MichaelButscher x starts from 1 and increments every time this line is run. the reason it is 11x - 6 is because the gridref line comes every 11 lines in the file, so it is always at line 11x - 6 where x is an integer, the rest of the lines are data. I have edited the question with more detail

Comment: @fre x starts from 1 and increments every time this line is run. the reason it is 11x - 6 is because the gridref line comes every 11 lines in the file, so it is always at line 11x - 6 where x is an integer, the rest of the lines are data. the ```line``` is part of a loop. I have edited the question with more detail

Comment: But, `if l == ((11*x) - 6):`? That doesn't look right. Is your indentation correct? What is `x`? It is not defined in your code snippet.

Comment: @quamrana ```x``` starts as 1. which part of that line doesnt look right?

Comment: Its just that `l == ((11*x) - 6)` will be `True` the first time round, but never again.

Comment: `line[11*x - 6:]` - should this just be `line` without any slicing?

Comment: @quamrana since ```x``` increments when this is true, it will be true every 11 lines. When i run it, this part works, it indeed goes into this if statement every 11 lines, it's just that it does not give the desired output

Comment: @slothrop sorry i dont understand

Comment: So `line` is an individual line. `line[11*x - 6:]` is that line with its leftmost (11x - 6) characters removed. Is that really what you want, or do you want to process the whole line?

Comment: Your `Grid-ref` lines are 22 lines apart.

Comment: @slothrop ```11*x - 6``` is simply the line number. The leftmost characters are removed by the ```replace()``` method.

Comment: @quamrana the actual file doesnt have any spaces between the lines. I added that in because the output on this originally showed without a defined start and end to each line, before i put it in code format. so they are 11 lines apart, i will change this back

Comment: `lines` is the list of lines, so `lines[11*x - 6]` would be the line with that number. But you  don't have `lines[11*x - 6]`, you have `line[11*x - 6]`.

Comment: Would you mind editing your question title to be more specific?

Comment: ah ok, yeah i think it should be line without the square brackets as ive already checked for the line in the if statement

Comment: Cool. You could also do `for line in lines[5::11]` and then you wouldn't need to do the math with `l` and `x`.

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36487709/how-to-iterate-over-every-n-th-line-from-a-file) help at all?

Comment: @quamrana thank you, the answers to my question worked for me, thanks for your time and assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code needs to sample every 22 lines and look into the `line` variable, and use `l` as the line counter:

```py
...
l = 5
x = 1
for line in lines[5:]:
   if l == ((22*x) - 17):
      xref, yref = line.replace("Grid-", "").replace("ref=", "").replace(" ", "").strip().split(',')
      print(xref, yref)   # example usage
      x = x + 1
   l = l + 1
```

Output:

```
1 148
1 311
1 312
```

Ok, so now that you've updated the question with the real file contents, I can go back to data 11 lines apart.

Also, you should use `enumerate()` to count the lines for you:

```py
x = 1
for l,line in enumerate(lines[5:], 5):
   if l == ((11*x) - 6):
      xref, yref = line.replace(" ", "").strip().split('=')[1].split(',')
      print(xref, yref)
      x = x + 1
```

Same output

Comment: thanks, that works, it actually is 11*x - 5 as the file doesnt have spaces between the lines, i just added that in on here as, originally it wasnt showing  a definite start and end for each line which i did it originally as i didnt have it in a code block

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have something like

```py
with open("input.txt", "r") as input:
    lines = input.readlines()
```

above the snippet you posted. This means that in your loop, the `line` variable will just hold a single line on every iteration so `line[11*x-6]` will be a substring of that line from position `11*x - 6`, meaning you chop off more and more of each line, before reading it, as `x` increases. The shortest path from where you are to a solution working *for this specific input* is probably to change

```py
      xref, yref = line[11*x - 6:].replace("Grid-", "").replace("ref=", "").replace(" ", "").strip().split(',')
```

to

```py
      xref, yref = line.replace("Grid-", "").replace("ref=", "").replace(" ", "").strip().split(',')
```

and outdenting the `l = l + 1` to be on the same level as the `if` statement. However, I would recommend going over the code in general to simplify it. For example, merge the replacements (you can get all of `Grid-ref=` in a single replacement) or replace everything with a regex search.

*Edit:* This assumes the input you are looking for is on every 11th line in the real input. As pointed out by @quamrana in his answer, the sample input you provided has the `Grid-ref`s every 22 lines but I assumed that was just a formatting error on the paste. Based on that I would reiterate my recommendation to look at something like a regex based solution since that allows you to use the regex result in your `if` statement, getting rid of both `l` and `x` altogether.